# Custom SQLFunctionTemplate on XML field causes escaping error if a Skip(..) LINQ section follows

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq, nhibernate

I have created a custom SQLFunctionTemplate to query an XML field for specific name/value pairs:

```
RegisterFunction("_ExistInCaratteristiche", 
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Boolean, 
                    "?1.exist('/L/I/C[N=sql:variable(\"?2\") and V=sql:variable(\"?3\")]') = 1"));
```

Which I use like this:

```
private IQueryable<MyEntity> _xmlFilter(IQueryable<MyEntity> input, string element, string value)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(element) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return input;

            return input.Where(m => m.XMLField.XMLContains(element.ToUpper(),value));
        }
```

and so, I can do:

```
..
IQueryable<MyEntity> result = Session.Query<MyEntity>();

            result = _xmlFilter(result, filter.element, filter.value);
            return result.ToList();    
..
```

**This is working correctly.**

Unfortunately, if I add a skip LINQ section after this custom filter, like this:

```
..
IQueryable<MyEntity> result = Session.Query<MyEntity>();

            result = _xmlFilter(result, filter.element, filter.value);
            result = result.Skip(3);
            return result.ToList();    
..
```

I get the following error when result.ToList() is called:

**Cannot find terminating ''' character for quoted text.**

I think I'm facing an escaping problem but I really have no idea why it happens only if I add a Skip LINQ section. I tried various combinations of quotes and single quotes in my SQLFunctionTemplate but I wasn't able to solve the issue.

**As requested by Oskar Berggren, here's the full stack-trace of the exception, which is thrown as soon as `nhibernate` tries to convert the `iqueryable` to the appropriate query (which is when `.ToList()` is invoked)**

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.SqlParseException: Cannot find terminating ''' character for quoted text.
   at NHibernate.SqlCommand.Parser.SqlParserUtils.ReadDelimitedText(String text, Int32 maxOffset, Int32 offset)
   at NHibernate.SqlCommand.Parser.SqlTokenizer.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at NHibernate.SqlCommand.Parser.SqlTokenizerExtensions.TryParseUntil(IEnumerator`1 tokenEnum, String keyword)
   at NHibernate.SqlCommand.Parser.SqlTokenizerExtensions.TryParseUntilFirstOrderColumn(IEnumerator`1 tokenEnum, SqlToken& orderToken)
   at NHibernate.SqlCommand.Parser.MsSqlSelectParser..ctor(SqlString sql)
   at NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005DialectQueryPager.PageByLimitAndOffset(SqlString offset, SqlString limit)
   at NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005DialectQueryPager.PageBy(SqlString offset, SqlString limit)
   at NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect.GetLimitString(SqlString queryString, SqlString offset, SqlString limit)
   at NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.GetLimitString(SqlString queryString, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 limit, Parameter offsetParameter, Parameter limitParameter)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.GetSqlStringWithLimitsIfNeeded(QueryWriter queryWriter)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.EndQuery()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.selectStatement()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SqlGenerator.statement()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlGenerator.Generate()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan.CreateTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan..ctor(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TRIM.Chibro.Services.Base.Operations.ListOdPOperation.Execute(ListOdPDto filter) in c:\Progetti.SVN.Cloud\Chibro\ChibroMES\src\TRIM.Chibro.Services\Base\Operations\ListOdPOperation.cs:line 30
   at TRIM.Chibro.Services.Implementations.ListOdPService.Execute(ListOdPDto filter) in c:\Progetti.SVN.Cloud\Chibro\ChibroMES\src\TRIM.Chibro.Services\Implementations\ListOdPService.cs:line 20
   at TRIM.Chibro.Web.Controllers.ListOdPController.Index(ListOdPModel model) in c:\Progetti.SVN.Cloud\Chibro\ChibroMES\src\TRIM.Chibro.Web\Controllers\ListOdPController.cs:line 75
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Right, so from where are you getting the exception, and which string exactly is it complaining about?

Comment: @OskarBerggren Sorry for the late reply but I've been on holiday. I included the full stack trace of the exception, which is trown as soon as Nhibernate tries to "convert" the IQueryable into the actual query (which is when ToList() is invoked). If there's any other information that you may need please just let me know how to retrieve it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the stack trace you can see that the problem comes from within GetLimitString() and its helpers, which answers your question about why it only happens with Skip() present. If there is no skip/take there is no reason to apply a limit/offset to the SQL and so therefore that method is never called.

As for the problem itself it's a bit difficult. NHibernate has to do some magic to the SQL to apply limit/offset with MSSQL dialects before 2012 since they lack straightforward SQL syntax for this feature.

I can't tell if there is a problem with escaping in your code, or if you are hitting a case for which NHibernate's MsSqlSelectParser wasn't designed.

If you grab the NHibernate source code and pdb-file, you can try debugging down into the top 5 lines of you stack trace and step trough it to see where exactly it goes wrong.